# offset calculation for day light saving(DST) without using localtime

Tags: c, time, epoch, dst, gmt

I have CODE as below to calculate offset,
Here I executed below code on EST timezone machine whose offset is -18000 seconds i.e. UTC-5.00

Please note I can't use `localtime()` due to some limitations which is very long story to mention here.
So I used below logic to do minus of GMT epoch from localtime epoch as below and it returned perfectly the offset.

Now what I want here is suppose case of DST(Day light Saving), where offset will be -14400 seconds i.e. UTC-4.00. Due to +1 adjustment of DST(Day light Saving) for EST time zone.

So will my code mentioned below work? in case system is having DST(Day light Saving).
I can not test live right now, as DST(Day light Saving) is not active on my machine.

Its planned as below:

```
/etc/localtime  Sun Mar 14 06:59:59 2021 UT = Sun Mar 14 01:59:59 2021 EST isdst=0 gmtoff=-18000
/etc/localtime  Sun Mar 14 07:00:00 2021 UT = Sun Mar 14 03:00:00 2021 EDT isdst=1 gmtoff=-14400
/etc/localtime  Sun Nov  7 05:59:59 2021 UT = Sun Nov  7 01:59:59 2021 EDT isdst=1 gmtoff=-14400
/etc/localtime  Sun Nov  7 06:00:00 2021 UT = Sun Nov  7 01:00:00 2021 EST isdst=0 gmtoff=-18000
```

So wanted to know, when DST is active, i.e. say between 14 March 2021 to 7 Nov 2021, will my below code return offset of -14400.
Does `time()` function consider epoch time after DST adjustment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime, g_epoch, l_epoch;
  struct tm * gtm, *ltm;
  signed long int offset;
  
  //Get current epoch time
  time ( &rawtime );
  
 // convert rawtime epoch to struct tm in GMT
  gtm = gmtime ( &rawtime );
// again convert back GMT struct tm to epoch
  g_epoch = mktime(gtm);

//convert rawtime epoch to "struct tm* ltm" in local time zone
  ltm= localtime(&rawtime);
// again convert back local time zone "struct tm* ltm" to epoch l_epoch
  l_epoch= mktime(ltm);
  

//calculate offset
  offset= l_epoch - g_epoch;
  
  printf("Rawtime: %u\n",rawtime);
 
  printf("GMTepoch: %u\n",g_epoch);

  printf("Local Epoch: %u\n",l_epoch);

  printf("Offset: %ld",offset);
  return 0;
}
```

```
O/p as below:
Rawtime: 1640176204
GMTepoch: 1640194204
Local Epoch: 1640176204
Offset: -18000
```

Comment: This is not an invalid approach.  I have used techniques like this, and something like this is recommended if you're trying to simulate the nonstandard `timegm` function.

Comment: @SteveSummit: Thanks but will this consider Day light Saving, say suppose system date is in between 14 March 2021 to 7 Nov 2021, will my below code return offset of -14400 offset for this machine which is in EST timezone.

Comment: Yes, it should work fine then too — that was implicit when I said "I have used techniques like this, and something like this is recommended if".  But I strongly recommend that you temporarily set your machine's clock back to two months ago and test your setup empirically.

Comment: @SteveSummit: Let me try that way to test.
Also wanted to know do u know any way to use this offset to adjust struct tm of GMT so that I will get struct tm* of localtime, same like which we get via localtime() call.

Comment: I assumed your plan was to take a `time_t` timestamp, add `Offset` to it, and then call `gmtime` instead of `localtime`.  You won't get the right answers for `tm_isdst` and `tm_gmtoff`, but the rest should be okay.

Comment: Finally, and I guess you know this, but I have to say that this is a horrible, horrible approach.  There is one right way to get a `struct tm` for local time and that is to call `localtime()`.  I remember [your post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70421981) explaining why you can't, and you have my sympathies, but I'm worried that something is still wrong, that the real root cause for your problem remains unaddressed, and is going to cause you some other problem(s) also.

Comment: my plan was to manually parse the offset seconds, and then adjust struct tm returned from `gmtime()`.

As even after passing offset adjusted epoch time to `gmtime()`, its same which is originally happening to pass output of ` time ( &rawtime );`,  which is same as my local epoch ` l_epoch` as printed in output.

Also, just now I set time to 
```
date -s  "5 Nov  2021 08:31:19 EDT"
Fri Nov  5 08:31:19 EDT 2021
```
But still my code returned output of -18000, while it should return -14400.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240343/discussion-between-amit-mendhe-and-steve-summit).

Comment: @SteveSummit:  This will not work as both are of different data type

Comment: Tip: `ltm= localtime(&rawtime); l_epoch= mktime(ltm);` is best written as `l_epoch = rawtime;`

Comment: `without using localtime` I do not really follow, just call `__localtime` then. Or use `localtime_r`. or `localtime64` or `localtime64_r` or `__localtime64` or ... or call `__tz_convert`.

Comment: @ikegami: yes, actually for testing the value, whether both `l_epoch` and `rawtime` are pointing to same I tried that way.
By this code I am able to get exact offset, but in case of DST active it fails to adjust DST hour.

Comment: @KamilCuk: Actually all calls down the line calls the code `parse_offset` which is causing issue on my env due to to legacy code linked with old OS and current code on latest platform of OS which cause some issue at register level in assembly code and that are getting accessed in `parse_offset()` which gets called from all the calls you mentioned.

Comment: :/ well, you do not explain the issue, then sure. Well, I see two other approuches: just `time()` call and parsing `/etc/localtime` manually (see `man tzfile`). Or just calling an external program, like `fopen("date +%z"`.

Comment: Why do you expect `mktime` to work if `localtime` doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making this small modification to your program:

```
gtm = gmtime (&rawtime);
gtm->tm_isdst = -1;
g_epoch = mktime(gtm);
```

it should work when DST is in effect.  Setting `tm_isdst` to -1 forces `mktime` to decide for itself whether DST is in effect.

You can also skip the manipulations involving `ltm` and `l_epoch` and the call to `localtime`.  (I thought the whole point of the exercise was to avoid calling `localtime`?)  You can compute your offset just fine with

```
offset = rawtime - g_epoch;
```

But in the end this is still a pretty dreadful hack, and as @ikegami has pointed out, it won't work properly in the vicinity of DST transitions.  For example, the `time_t` value 1636261200 properly corresponds to 1am EDT on November 7, 2021, but this code will wrongly determine that it has already fallen back to EST.  This problem will be worse (will apply for a larger number of hours) the farther your local time zone is from GMT.  There's probably a way around this, but it won't be particularly pretty.

Comment: You are great, thanks a lot, it really worked and actually getting result what I was expecting.
Current Time: System is in DST time
`# date`
`Sun Mar 14 05:38:55 EDT 2021`

my application o/p

`Offset: -14400`
Which is perfectly dst adjusted offset.

Comment: No, this fails at 2022-03-12T22:30:00 for the reasons my earlier explained

Comment: @ikegami: It worked perfectly by setting gtm->tm_isdst = -1;

Comment: @Amit Mendhe, You tested with a time after the change. The time I posted is before the change. It should give -18000 but it gives -14400.

Comment: Answer updated.  This technique ain't gonna be perfect, but it'll work well enough *most* of the time...

Comment: @ikegami:
Before DST change:
date: Wed Mar 10 01:59:55 EST 2021,
Offset: -18000
After DST change:Sun Mar 14 05:38:55 EDT 2021
Offset: -14400
I just now tested it.
Its working

Comment: @Amit Mendhe, `Wed Mar 10 01:59:55 EST 2021,` isn't `2022-03-12T22:30:00`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xc9v84v71) of the bug. There's a similar failure in the fall.

Comment: Thanks @ikegami pointing on the loopholes with this I will consider the problematic use case.

Comment: [Demo of spring and fall problem](https://godbolt.org/z/G1z9Y3Y3Y) (I had incorrect values in earlier version)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will work at all, but I'm not sure. Best case, it will give incorrect results near switches to/from DST.

If you can't trust the system time zone database, you can always use your own copy of the [tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). Steve Summit points out the database even comes with a reference implementation of all the time zone-related functions such as `localtime`, so there would be no need to parse the database yourself.

Note: The database is frequently updated, so you will need some kind of process to update your application frequently if you need to work with arbitrary time zones.

---

> *Does time() function consider epoch time after DST adjustment.*

`time` returns the number of seconds since the start of 1970 UTC.

As such, the result doesn't change where you are in the world.

```
Local time                  Time Zone Examples   time()
-------------------------   ------------------   ----------
2021-06-01T12:00:00Z        Etc/UTC, E./Dublin   1622548800
2021-06-01T08:00:00-04:00   "EDT", A./New_York   1622548800
2021-06-01T07:00:00-05:00   "EST", A./Bogota     1622548800

2021-06-01T12:00:00Z        Etc/UTC, E./Dublin   1622548800
2021-06-01T12:00:00-04:00   "EDT", A./New_York   1622563200
2021-06-01T12:00:00-05:00   "EST", A./Bogota     1622566800
```

---

> So will my code mentioned below work? in case system is having DST(Day light Saving).

Doesn't `mktime` take it's information about local time from the same place `localtime` does? So why would `mktime` work on a system where `localtime` doesn't?

But let's say `mktime` does work.

Even if we assume that `mktime` works correctly on a system where `localtime` doesn't, I don't think it will work. I think `gtm.tm_isdst` will always be zero (since `gmtime` uses UTC which doesn't have DST), and I think that will cause the following `mktime` to return something different than desired. But this can be addressed by setting `gtm .tm_isdst` to `-1`.

So let's say `mktime` does return what we expect.

Even if `mktime` returns what we expect, the approach is flawed. It will give the wrong offsets near switches to/from DST.

```c
// Current time zone:  America/New_York
// Current local time: 2022-03-12T22:30:00-05:00
// Change to DST:      In 3.5 hours.

// Get the current epoch time.
// This returns the same thing worldwide.
time(&rawtime);              // rawtime = 1647142200

// Convert current epoch time to UTC.
gtm = gmtime(&rawtime);      // gtm = 2021-03-13T03:30:00
gtm .tm_isdst = -1;

// Note that mktime expects a local time.
// But we're passing the current UTC time.
// So g_epoch is the epoch time for
// 2021-03-13T03:30:00 America/New_York
g_epoch = mktime(gtm);       // rawtime = 1647156600
```

And there's the problem. `2021-03-13T03:30:00` (local) is after the change to DST, but we're only `2022-03-12T22:30:00` (local), which is still before the change to DST. This is going to give us the wrong offset.

Comment: As I checked, time(), returns seconds,epoch time irrespective of DST is active or not.
I even tested by changing system date to 
date -s  "14 Mar 2021 01:59:55 EST"
And then allowed DST to happen and then executed my code.
It still returned offset of -18000,while it should return -14400.

So this concludes, `time()` call will not consider /adjust epoch time if DST is active.

Comment: @Amit Mendhe, No, `time()` has absolutely nothing to do with the problem. As I explained, the problem is that the value returned by `mktime`  has `0` for `tm_isdst` since `gmtime` uses UTC which doesn't have DST.

Comment: But my code is working perfectly to get offset if DST is not active. only this causes issues if DST is active and it doesnt give offset adjusted. I was thinking function `time()` could fetch me `rawtime` dst adjusted.

Comment: Re "*But my code is working perfectly to get offset if DST is not active*", Yes, because the `tm_isdst` returned by `gmtime` happens to be correct then.

Comment: Yes, right. But thanks it concluded that my aproach will not work, I will need to think of any other approach to calculate offset considering DST switch as well.

Comment: Use the [time zone database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) to get the offsets based on `time()`

Comment: For that matter, the time zone database contains a reference implementation of all the timezone-related functions, so you could use the implementation of `localtime` that's in there, too.  (That is, you certainly don't need to write your own code to parse the timezone files, or perform the offset calculations.)

Comment: @Steve Summit, Cool, I did not know that. I normally use said DB via the DateTime Perl module ([Example](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/5ec4c9ca3b091eca9d6ee86dca0b439a)), and I've never looked closely at it. That sounds like exactly what the OP needs. I'll paraphrase your comment in my answer.

Comment: @ikegami: yes actually that was in my mind to consider below system call:
 zdump -v  /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York | grep 2021, 
But it will increase load on my application as system() call to execute above command will be heavy

Comment: @SteveSummit: Thanks but can you elaborate more on this, I am not getting exactly about >> time zone database contains a reference implementation of all the timezone-related functions, any example you can suggest

Comment: <strike>He means it contains a version of `localtime` you can use instead of the system one.</strike> Apparently, not. I'll let him explain.

Comment: Well, no, not quite.  You can use that reference code to read either a fresh copy of the tz database you downloaded and built, or the copy of the tz database that's already resident on your system.  My point was that if the solution to "I can't call `localtime`" is "then you should read the timezone database files and perform the offset calculations yourself, perhaps going so far as to write your own implementation of `localtime`", then no, you don't actually have to write any of that code, you can use the code that comes with the tz database.  Or you can see my newly-posted answer.

Comment: (But really, you need to get rid of that gawdawful third-party library that's preventing you from calling `sscanf` or `localtime` or who knows what else.  Disaster waiting to happen, that is.)

Comment: @SteveSummit: By your line >>>you can use the code that comes with the tz database
Does it mean we have some other functions to access tz database and do calculations

Comment: @SteveSummit, ikegami: Even if there is any way to get to know that dst is active then also my half job is done.

Comment: @AmitMendhe You have a copy of `localtime()` in your C library which you've determined you can't use.  But at https://www.iana.org/time-zones you can download (among other things) a file `localtime.c` which contains someone else's implementation of `localtime()` which might — might! — work better for you.  Given all the other problems you've been having, though, I can't promise that downloading, building, and linking against that alternative version will be a feasible approach for you.

Comment: *you will need some kind of process to update your application frequently* Not necessarily.  The tzfile format rarely changes, so you can usually get away with pointing your code at the system-installed (and hopefully regularly updated) files in `/usr/share/zoneinfo` or wherever.

Comment: @Steve Summit, Is the the problem that those aren't valid? Why else couldn't you use `localtime`?

Comment: Why couldn't you build and use the `localtime` from the tzcode reference implementation?  Only because, downloading and building sources from the Internet is a bit of a lost art; it's not like typing `apt-get` or `yum` or whatever.  (Also it's arguably asking for trouble to compile and link into your application a function with the same name as a standard library function.  Also the Makefile that comes with the tzcode package thinks the installed zoneinfo files are going to be in a certain place, and it's not necessarily obvious how to tweak things if your system has 'em somewhere else.)

Comment: @Steve Summit, Re "*Why couldn't you build and use the localtime from the tzcode reference implementation?*", huh? noone asked that.

Comment: @ikegami When I said "you can use the code that comes with the tz database", I think Amit Mendhe thinks that's what they can do.  As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70421981), they evidently can't use the `localtime` in their system's native C library.

Comment: Maybe I missed what you meant when you said "Is the the problem that those aren't valid? Why else couldn't you use `localtime`"?

Comment: @Steve Summit Isn't the problem that `/usr/share/zoneinfo` isn't valid? Why else couldn't you use `localtime`?

Comment: Ah. AIUI, the OP can't use the installed version of `localtime` because it calls `sscanf`, and  any call to `sscanf` in the OP's program crashes because the stack is corrupted by a third-party library they're compelled to use.  See the OP's [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70421981). There's no suggestion (that I've seen) that there's anything wrong with the zoneinfo files.

Comment: @Steve Summit I see. Then yes, that would be a good solution

Comment: @SteveSummit:
By running shell command `zdump -v  /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York | grep 2021`, I get time when DST will become active, is there any way or function to get the start date and end date of DST for perticular year, rather than using shell command.
Like below:`zdump -v /etc/localtime -c $(date '+%Y'),$(date -d '+1 year' '+%Y') | awk -v y=$(date '+%Y') '$6==y && $15~1 {print $5, $4, $3, $6}'`
Which return 
`07:00:00 14 Mar 2021`
`05:59:59 7 Nov 2021`

Comment: @SteveSummit: Main moto is to fetch start date and end date of DST in c code.

Comment: @AmitMendhe *is there any way or function to get the start date and end date of DST* I doubt there is a nice, easy, prewritten way to do this in C.